# What does the SQL "Select 42" do and how to turn it off in Sybase?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

We are using Sybase ASE as our DBMS. I've noticed that every query to the DB server is preceded by a "Select 42" call. What exactly does this do?

It seems that it is just a test/ping, is this correct, where does it originate from and how can we turn it off?

Can't seem to find any real documentation on this.

Comment: `It seems that it is just a test/ping` In deed it is. And in a geekish way :) It comes from the [Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) No, really: it comes from whatever DB abstraction layer you are using in your application.

Comment: It could be a validation query from your connection pool.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name where do I go to check this? select 42 does not exist in the codebase. This is a webapp running on IIS

Comment: Wherever your connection pool is configure. You should know where that configuration file is. Somewhere in your application server (Tomcat/Glassfish/JBoss/... or IIS directly)

Comment: Thanks horse, I used to have full unadulterated access to the web-server at the start-up company, but now at the large corporate It's a dream. Suppose I'll get an answer from the network admins some day so don't be surprised if this thread suddenly comes alive again somewhere in the distant future :) thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 2):

it is just a simple test, most likely to check if the connection to the DB is still active. Using Sybase ASE you can SELECT on nothing really and just create a "test function". Like so: SELECT 1 + 1